# Google Maps Lat/Long finder script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am looking everywhere for a script where I can add an address or postcode in an input box and have the google latitute and longitute displayed in another input box.

I found that this website does this:

http://www.doogal.co.uk/LatLong.php

But I don't need that much, just looking for the part where you have the Search,    Latitude and Longitude parts.

Can anyone provide any information or url or script to do this?

All I find around is Address to Map .... I just need Address to Latitude and Longitude.

Comment: According to the Google TOS, you have to use the Geocoding stuff on a Google Map, otherwise it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Google Maps API, it is very simple to geocode an address. `address` is a textfield that the user inputs a street address. `latlng` is a text field that holds the outputted lat/long.

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode( {'address': $('#address').val() }, function(data, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      $('#latlng').val(data[0].geometry.location.lat+", "+data[0].geometry.location.lng);
    else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

See https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 1):

the code they're using on [that page](http://www.doogal.co.uk/LatLong.php) is:

```
function Geocode()
            {
                $("#locations").html("");
                $("#error").html("");
                // geocode with google.maps.Geocoder
                var localSearch = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var postcode = $("#postcode").val();
                localSearch.geocode({ 'address': postcode },
                    function(results, status) {
                        if (results.length == 1) {
                            var result = results[0];
                            var location = result.geometry.location;
                            GotoLocation(location);
                        }
                        else if (results.length > 1) {
                            $("#error").html("Multiple addresses found");
                            // build a list of possible addresses
                            var html = "";
                            for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
                                html += '<a href="javascript:GotoLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(' + 
                                    results[i].geometry.location.lat() + ', ' + results[i].geometry.location.lng() + '))">' + 
                                    results[i].formatted_address + "</a><br/>";
                            }
                            $("#locations").html(html);
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#error").html("Address not found");
                        }
                    });
            }
```

`#postcode` is where you type the address on the side of that site, and `results[i].geometry.location.lat() + ', ' + results[i].geometry.location.lng()` in the `for` loop would be your lat/long...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an API key and implement the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

Alternatively, [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/help/) also offers a free solution.

Answer (score 0):

i build a Latitude & Longitude Finder for my Website:

**See:** https://www.revilodesign.de/tools/google-maps-latitude-longitude-finder/

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
 
 var markers = [];
 
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('address')),{
  types: ['geocode']
 });
 
 var myLatLng = {
  lat   : 52.520008,
  lng   : 13.404954
 };
  
 var map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom  : 2,
  center  : myLatLng
 });
 
 
 // START BY CLICK
 jQuery('div#find').on('click', function() {
  LatLngSearch();   
 });
 
 // START BY PRESS ENTER
 jQuery('#address').bind("enterKey",function(e){
  LatLngSearch(); 
 });
 jQuery('#address').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13) {
   LatLngSearch();
  }
 });
 
 // DELETE ALL MARKERS
 function DeleteMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   markers[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markers = [];
 };
 
 // SHOW LAT LNG  
 function LatLngSearch(  ) {
  
  var value = jQuery('input#address').val();
  
  if ( value ) {
   var request  = $.ajax({
    url   : "ajax.php",
    method  : "POST",
    data  : { 
         address  : value
        },
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(result) {
   
     console.log(result);
     
     if ( result['lat'] && result['lng'] ) {
     
      DeleteMarkers();
     
      jQuery('div#geometry').append('<p><strong>Latitude:</strong> <input readonly="" value="' + result['lat'] + '" /></p>');
       
      jQuery('div#geometry').append('<p><strong>Longitude:</strong> <input readonly="" value="' + result['lng'] + '" /></p>');
      
      var searchLatLng = {
       lat   : result['lat'],
       lng   : result['lng']
      };
      
      // CENTER MAP
      var map  = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom  : 14,
       center  : searchLatLng
      });
      
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map   : map,
       position : searchLatLng,
       animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
               });
               
               var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       content: '<strong>Lat:</strong> ' + result['lat'] + '<br><strong>Lng:</strong> ' + result['lng']
      });
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
      
      // ADD MARKER TO ARRAY
      markers.push(marker);
     }
     
    },
    error  : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
     alert(xhr.status);
     alert(thrownError);
    }
   });
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<div id="finder">
 <div id="finder-search">
  <input id="address" type="text" />
  <div id="find" class="btn button scale-minus">Search</div>
 </div>
 <div id="geometry"></div>
 <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

and the ajax.php

```
$address            =   $_POST['address'];
$address            =   str_replace(array('ä','ü','ö','ß'), array('ae', 'ue', 'oe', 'ss'), $address );
$address            =   preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\s]/", "", $address);
$address            =   strtolower($address);
$address            =   str_replace( array(' ', '--'), array('-', '-'), $address );                     
$address            =   'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&key=YOUR_API_KEY';

$json               =   file_get_contents($address);
$obj                =   json_decode($json); 

$datas['lat']       =   $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$datas['lng']       =   $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

echo json_encode( $datas );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="address">Lat Long of Location :</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter Address to Find Lat Long">
                  <input id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Lat Long" />
                          <input id="lat" type="hidden"/>
                      <input id="lng" type="hidden"/>
                </div>
                </form>




          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
           <label for="lati">Latitude : </label><input id="lati" type="text" disabled />
            <label for="longi">Longitude : </label><input id="longi" type="text" disabled />
          </div>

          <div id="latlong"></div>
          <div id="temp"></div>
<div id="map"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
simply add
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY&#38;callback=initMap" async defer/>


<script>
      function initMap() {
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           zoom: 8,
           center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
         });
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
           geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
         });
       }

       function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
         var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
         if( address===''){
 alert("Please Enter Address to find Latitude Longitude...!!!!!!");
 return false;
 }

         geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status === 'OK') {
             resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
              var info="<h4> Latitude and Longitude : "+results[0].geometry.location+"</h4>";
              var latlo="<h3>Lat Long of  "+address+"   "+results[0].geometry.location+"</h3>";
             var latlong1 = latlo;
              document.getElementById('latlong').innerHTML=latlong1;
              document.getElementById('lat').value=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
              document.getElementById('lng').value=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
               document.getElementById('lati').value=results[0].geometry.location.lat();


              var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: info
         });

             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               map: resultsMap,
               position: results[0].geometry.location,
               title: 'LatLongfinder Result'
             });

              infowindow.setContent(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
         infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);

           } else {
             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
           }
         });
       }
     </script>
```

I have used that in my Website [latlongfinder](https://www.latlongfinder.net)